# Why is my list of parent items growing without adding items

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a simple core-data/swiftui test app with 2 entities. 1: Item entity with a simple text and timestamp attributes. And a one-to-one relationship to an Editor entity. 2: editor entity with a name attribute and a one-to-many relationship to Item.
In the item view I want to pick an editor from a list of stored Editors. However when I update the view (i.e. adding text to the text attribute), the list of editors to pick from grows with new and empty editor objects.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ItemEditView(item: item),
                        label: {
                            Text(item.text ?? "No text")
                        })
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }.navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(), trailing:
                                    HStack {
                                        
                                        NavigationLink(
                                            destination: PersonEditView(editor: Editor(context: viewContext)),
                                            label: {
                                                Label("Add Editor", systemImage: "person")
                                            })
                                        Button(action: addItem) {
                                            Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                                        }
                                    }
            )
        }
    }
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                viewContext.rollback()
            }
        }
    }
    private func addPerson() {
        withAnimation {
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}

struct ItemEditView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    @FetchRequest private var editors: FetchedResults<Editor>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    var body: some View {
        TextField("text", text: $item.text.bound)
        Text(item.text ?? "Hello")
        Text(item.editor?.name ?? "No name")
        List{
            ForEach(editors) { editor in
                Button(editor.name ?? "no name") {
                    editor.addToItems(item)
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: save, label: {Text("save")}))
    }
    init(item: Item) {
        let personRequest: NSFetchRequest<Editor> = Editor.fetchRequest()
        personRequest.fetchLimit = 10
        personRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Editor.name, ascending: true)]
        _editors = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: personRequest)
        self.item = item
    }
    
    private func save() {
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            viewContext.rollback()
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

struct PersonEditView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject var editor: Editor
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TextField("name", text: $editor.name.bound)
        }.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: save, label: {
            Text("Save")
        }))
        
    }
    private func save() {
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            viewContext.rollback()
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}


extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var _bound: String? {
        get {
            return self
        }
        set {
            self = newValue
        }
    }
    public var bound: String {
        get {
            return _bound ?? ""
        }
        set {
            _bound = newValue.isEmpty ? nil : newValue
        }
    }
}
```

[Project on github](https://github.com/guillaume5380/coreDataTest)

[Core data model: Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9fUX.png) [Core data model: Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chRN5.png)
For the looks you can always filter out using an if statement. Although it doesn't seem to me that this is an ideal option. The bigger thing is that when I try to save the context, all those extra empty editors get saved as well.
Is there a way to not have empty editors added to my list and managedObjectContext?

Comment: Can't reproduce with the code you provided. Nothing in your code creates editors. The only thing this code does is swap the `editor` that owns the passed `item` since you can only assign one `editor` to an `item`.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: It is also important to show the actual Core Data model. This can be done by screenshotting each entity and uploading the screenshots.

Comment: My bad. Just added the rest of my code and core data model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an `Editor` every time the `ContentView` `body` is reloaded.

Comment out this code and it won't happen anymore. How to fix it? Take persistence code out of any `View` `struct` it doesn't belong there.

Put it into a `class` `ViewModel` or a `Manager` and just call methods/ pass variables with the `View` actions.

```
//                    NavigationLink(
//                        The issue is this line. 
//                        destination: PersonEditView(editor: Editor(context: viewContext)),
//                        label: {
//                            Label("Add Editor", systemImage: "person")
//                        })
```

SwiftUI pre-loads a lot of code/`View`s it is a known behavior that developers have to adjust too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made a view model. And when tapping save I convert the view model to the core data model and save the context. Or do you have any other recommendations? With lots of attributes this can get quit tedious I imagine

Comment: That is a matter of preference/opinion I use MVC. Persistence is done in a manager I create the object upon init of the ViewModel and and have a way to “rollback” if the user decides do cancel

Comment: Oh at one point,  I created twin Non-Managed versions of my CoreData objects and they had a function called makeManaged() that would switch them over and return the managed version. It just depends on your style.